# How can a statistic be random variable?

Tags: probability, statistics, definition

Random variable is a real valued function from **sample space (population)** to $\mathbb{R}$

$X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Let $S \subset \Omega$ be an event (sample).

Then a function on $S$ can be called as statistic. Thus, a statistic $s$ can be defined as a function from **powerset of sample space (population)** $2^{\Omega}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

$s : 2^{\Omega} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

I heard from several sources that *a statistic is a random variable*.

How can a statistic can be a random variable if **domains** are different?

Comment: It fits the definition, but the sample space is different.  Instead of being the original $\Omega$, it is larger

Answer (score 3):

As you say, the definition of a random variable is a (measurable) real-valued function from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb R$. We changed the $\Omega$, sure, but a statistic (as you defined it) still fits that definition perfectly.

Let's flesh this out with a concrete example: suppose you have 10 people, and you'll randomly choose one of them for your sample. Here, $\Omega$ is just the collection of 10 people -- that is, $|\Omega| = 10$ -- and the height function $H: \Omega \to \mathbb R$ which measures the height of the random person is a random variable in the sense described at the top of your question.

Now, let's take a random sample of 3 people from our group, and we'll let $\overline H$ denote their *average* height. Intuitively, it's clear that this must be a random variable, because the value of $\overline H$ will depend upon which three people happen to land in our sample. How this happens, mechanically, is that the new sample space is no longer what we used to call $\Omega$, but instead $2^{\Omega}$ (you could just call it $\Omega'$, if you like). Note that since we stipulated we wanted to draw a group of size $3$, we could impose a probability measure that is uniform on all elements of $\Omega'$ that happen to be sets of size 3, and zero on all other sets.

This perfectly fits your original definition of a random variable; we have a probability space, $\Omega'$, equipped with a probability distribution, and a measurable real-valued function on it. There's no particular rule that the phrase "random variable" must refer to the same $\Omega$ in all cases.